# Closing a stream server socket is slow

Tags: php, sockets

Closing the resource returned from `stream_socket_server()` is extremely slow (~0.5 seconds), as tested by this script:

```
<?php

echo "Creating socket...";
$s = stream_socket_server("tcp://127.0.0.1:4567");
echo "done\n";

echo "Closing socket...";
fclose($s);
echo "done\n";

?>
```

90% of the execution time is spent on `fclose($s);`

The equivalent C++ application does not encounter this length of delay attempting to shut down a listening socket, instead closing in < 0.03 seconds. Is there a PHP-specific configuration that affects this?

- **OS:** Windows 7 x64 Ultimate
- **PHP:** 5.4.0 (cli)
- **Config**: Default `php.ini`

Comment: Cannot reproduce on PHP 5.3.10. Please post your OS, PHP version and config.

Comment: I'm able to execute that script 100 times over in about 1.4 seconds on Ubuntu 12.04, PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.1 with Suhosin-Patch.

Comment: fclose takes about 0.5seconds on win 7 64, php 5.4 rc2

Comment: @chris - Thats a similar timeframe to what I'm experiencing. Definitely much longer than the previous commenter. Have a feeling its related to the OS/PHP combination...

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

So, what happens here is, you're not just waiting for the application to close the socket, but you also need to wait for the open TCP socket to close at the network layer.

When you have an open socket, a FIN from the server and peer are required to close the socket, or if a FIN is received by either side, the default timeout (mostly 600 seconds depending on setup).

Something you can try to help speed this up is closing your socket with:

```
stream_socket_shutdown
```

Comment: I see zero performance improvement when using `stream_socket_shutdown` vs `fclose`. Tested with all combinations of shutdown flags.